# How do I get data-value of the select option where I triggered the change() function and use that to open its modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select input dropdown that calls a function (openModal) when the "3" value is selected:

```
$('.statusButtonChange').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') changeStatus($(this).attr('data-value'));
    else if ($(this).val() == '3')  openModal();
    else changeWork($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

This is my openModal function:

```
function openModal(x) {
(function ($) {

    $('#alarm-DATAVALUEOFTHESELECTOPTIONTHATTRIGGEREDTHISFUNCTION').modal('show'); 
    })(jQuery);
}
```

And my html:

```
    <select class="statusButtonChange statusButton " data-value="46024">
    <option value="0" selected=""></option>
    <option value="1">Close</option>
    <option value="2">Open</option>
    <option value="3">Disable</option>
    </select>

 <div id="alarm-'.$element['eventId'].'" class="modal fade modal-alert">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Title
                        </div>
                         <div class="modal-body" id="boxPopUpPushCommand" style="text-align:left !important">
                            Body texts here 


                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I have multiple modals, with different div ids, depending on the data-value from my PHP code. Data-value can also be taken from the data-value inside my select html. Is there a way to get the data-value of the select option where i triggered the change() function? I'm not sure if I made sense but I hope you get what I mean. I want to be able to show just the modal of a certain data-value where I did the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$('.statusButtonChange').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == '1') changeStatus($(this).attr('data-value'));
   else if ($(this).val() == '3')  openModal($(this).attr('data-value'));
   else changeWork($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

...

```
function openModal(x) {
   $('#alarm-' + x).modal('show');
}
```